# Stackdriver and Airflow Execution

Tags: monitoring, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-composer

I have my DAG executed by Google Composer, and I want to configure an email Alert in Stack driver so that I get email notifications when specific errors occur in DAG. I am already doing this alert in my Dataflows executed by Composer, but I am unable to find a way to capture the errors/exceptions occurring in DAG to trigger an alert through Stackdriver. There are no DAG specific metrics that we are finding in Stackdriver. Unfortunately SendGrid/ SMTP is not an option for us. Could you help with any workaround?

Comment: Have you tried using the email_on_failure property?

Comment: But, this also requires SMTP or SendGrid configured for the composer, right?